# How to make tree from child of parent categories?

Tags: php, data-structures, tree

I have a problem when i want to create tree structure in my data this is my data for sample

```
$categories = array(
    array(
        'id' => 2 ,
        'name' => 'banana',
        'parent' => 1
    ),

    array(
        'id' => 1 ,
        'name' => 'fruit',
        'parent' => 0
    ),

    array(
        'id' => 3 ,
        'name' => 'Monkey',
        'parent' => 4
    ),

    array(
        'id' => 4 ,
        'name' => 'Animal',
        'parent' => 0
    ),

    array(
        'id' => 5 ,
        'name' => 'apple',
        'parent' => 1
    ),

    array(
        'id' => 6 ,
        'name' => 'Cat',
        'parent' => 4
    ),

    array(
        'id' => 7 ,
        'name' => 'Animal Water',
        'parent' => 1
    ),

    array(
        'id' => 8 ,
        'name' => 'fish',
        'parent' => 7
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 9 ,
        'name' => 'frog',
        'parent' => 7
    )
);
```

then I want to restructure that array to be like this

```
$fix = array(

    array(
        'id' => 4 ,
        'name' => 'Animal',
        'parent' => 0,
        'child' => array(
            array(
                'id' => 7 ,
                'name' => 'Animal Water',
                'parent' => 1,
                'child' => array(
                    array(
                        'id' => 8 ,
                        'name' => 'fish',
                        'parent' => 7
                    ),
                    array(
                        'id' => 9 ,
                        'name' => 'frog',
                        'parent' => 7
                    )
                )
            ),

            array(
                'id' => 3 ,
                'name' => 'Monkey',
                'parent' => 4
            ),

            array(
                'id' => 6 ,
                'name' => 'Cat',
                'parent' => 4
            ),
        )
    ),

    array(
        'id' => 1 ,
        'name' => 'fruit',
        'parent' => 0,
        'child' => array(
            array(
                'id' => 2 ,
                'name' => 'banana',
                'parent' => 1
            ),



            array(
                'id' => 5 ,
                'name' => 'apple',
                'parent' => 1
            )
        )
    )

);
```

so I tried using this function , but not helped me out.

```
$GLOBALS['viyancs'] = array();
$GLOBALS['i'] = 0;
function finding_parent($categories) {

    foreach ($categories as $value) {

        //finding parent
        if ($value['parent'] === 0 ) {
            $GLOBALS['viyancs'][$GLOBALS['i']][$value['id']]= $value;
            $GLOBALS['i']++;
            continue;
        }

        if (isset($GLOBALS['viyancs'][$GLOBALS['i']][$value['parent']])) {
            $GLOBALS['viyancs'][$GLOBALS['i']][$value['parent']]['child']= $value;
        }
        $GLOBALS['i']++;
    }
    return $GLOBALS['viyancs'];
}

var_dump(finding_parent($categories));
```

any other suggestion ?

Comment: It looks as though you're essentially building a nested navigation system... the best way I've found to do this is to parse it into XML (using DOMDocument) then you can assign ids to nodes (like `id="c{$iCatId}`) and attach child nodes to their parents with standard DOM manipulation. The biggest advantages are that you can use XPath to navigate or start at the bottom of a tree and work your way up very easily ... the downside, of course, is that you have to parse everything into XML - but that's much better than recursive loops I think.

Comment: hii, it's look i heard new another solution , can you explain more about this, or give me reference about your suggestion ?

Comment: I wrote a small article about it on a blog a couple of years back... I'll post a version of it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the problem:

You've got a navigation system of undefined depth that you want the user to be able to drill down through, so something like products » electronics » audio » MP3 players. So you set up a database for the navigation system and to keep it nice and clean you can effectively minimise it to something like:

```
Table: nav

id  parent_id       name
----------------------------------------------------------
1       0           'Products'
2       1           'Electronics'
3       2           'Audio'
4       3           'MP3 Players'
```

This gives you a nice structure where all your navigation items have parents (or not if they're top level) and, as long as you're drilling down it's fine... the problem comes when you want to "drill up"!

See, to keep the URI clean you only really want to pass in the navigation id and use that to build up your page. So if you're URI passing a variable like `?nav=4` then the system has to know which navigation items will be visible when `nav=4`; e.g. the parent (and siblings) of nav 4, the parent and siblings of that nav... and so on all the way down the tree to the root level items.

I've seen this done in a dozen different ways - most involve horrible recursive loops and I've always thought there has to be a better way.

One alternative is to store the "path" in the database for each navigation item. It's nicely efficient, you just add in a VARCHAR field and store the path to the nav item as a serialised string... something like "1;2;3;4".

However that's never "sat right" with me. It just seems *wrong* to store the structure of the data that way when it's already there - in the form of the parent_id. It breaks the relational aspect of your data because if you move a navigation item you've got to not only reassign the parent_id but also rebuild that path - say you wanted to drop the Audio sub-category and just move MP3 Players into the Electronics category. With the basic database structure you just drop nav.id = 3, reassign the parent_id and jobsagoodun. If you're storing the path however you also need to update that path so that instead of "1;2;3;4" it now reads "1;2;4".

From the point of view of maintaining the relational integrity of the data, this has always seemed like a bad idea to me.

---

***The solution***

Since we want to store the data in a structured fashion - why not convert it to a structured fashion? XML.

First off we map the entire navigation system to XML - so we need to select it first.

```
SELECT nav.id, nav.parent_id, nav.name FROM nav
```

Now we need to loop through that data and map it to an XML structure - I'm using a database abstraction object so assume a read method executes a SELECT query on the database and returns a multi-dimensional array like:

```
array ( 
  [0] => array ( 'id' => 1, 'parent_id' => 0, 'name' => "Products" ), 
  [1] => array ( 'id' => 2, 'parent_id' => 1, 'name' => "Electronics" ), 
  ... and so on 
);
```

So if you do a for loop on that array, every instance will be an associative array holding the navigation item data ... now to structure it.

```
$xml = new DOMDocument(); 
$xmlRoot = $xml->createElement('root'); 
$xml->appendChild($xmlRoot); 

//order by the parent ID so that when attaching nodes the parents will exist first 
$aNavList = $db->read("SELECT nav.id, nav.parent_id, nav.name FROM nav ORDER BY nav.parent_id ASC"); 

foreach($aNavList as $aNavItem) {
  $iParentID = (int) $aNavItem['parent_id']; 

  //create the 'nav' node containing the text: e.g. <nav>Products</nav> 
  $xmlNav = $xml->createElement('nav', $aNavItem['name']); 

  //assign attributes to the nav node to store the data 
  // XML IDs can't start with numbers 
  $xmlNav->setAttribute('id', "nav_{$aNavItem['id']}"); 
  $xmlNav->setIdAttribute('id', true); 

  // the pure database ID 
  $xmlNav->setAttribute('db_id', $aNavItem['id']); 

  //Attach the nodes to the XML document 
  // If the parent ID of this node is 0, attach to the 'root' element 
  // Otherwise attach to the element with the ID "nav_{this parent id}" 
  $xmlParentNode = $iParentID == 0 ? 
      $xmlRoot : 
      $xml->getElementById("nav_{$aNavItem['parent_id']}"); 

  $xmlParentNode->appendChild($xmlNav); 
}
```

The $xml variable should now hold a structured version of your navigation data, thus:

```
<root>
    <nav id="nav_1" db_id="1" page_id="1">Products 
        <nav id="nav_2" db_id="2" page_id="2">Electronics 
            <nav id="nav_3" db_id="3" page_id="3">Audio 
                <nav id="nav_4" db_id="4" page_id="4">MP3 Players</nav> 
            </nav>
        </nav>
    </nav>
</root>
```

I'll admit that's not terribly exciting but it does mean that you can use standard DOM navigation techniques to run through your nav system. Remember, we've only got the ID of the LAST node in that branch of the navigation tree but now that node is nested within all its ancestors. Now we can navigate through that data upwards!

Say we've got a huge, nested navigation system and we want to make a breadcrumb trail all we need is the node we're looking for and any direct ancestors of that node - so that we end up with something like the aforementioned:

**Products » Electronics » Audio » MP3 Players**

We can now do this without an unknown quantity or recursive loops using the DOMDocument stored in $xml and the nav variable from the address - e.g. products.php?nav=4

```
$iNavSoughtID = (int) $_GET['nav']; 
$htmlBreadcrumb = ""; 
$xmlNodeSought = $xml->getElementById("nav_{$iNavSoughtID}"); 

while($xmlNodeSought->nodeName != 'root') { 
    $htmlBreadcrumb .= '<a href="/products.php?nav=' 
                    . $xmlNodeSought->getAttribute('db_id') . '">' 
                    . $xmlNodeSought->firstChild->nodeValue 
                    . '</a>'; 

    $xmlNodeSought = $xmlNodeSought->parentNode; 
}
```

That's a really simple example without any security or sanity checks in but it does give you a working breadcrumb trail where you've just started with the node identified in the address and worked your way down the xml tree until you've hit the root - without any horrible recursive loops or questionable path data in the database.

If you store your navigation system in XML you need only perform the one single database query at the start to build the document and then you can perform all the navigation views through simple DOM manipulation. You could even have the CMS actually write (and update) a navigation XML document and use JavaScript (AJaX) to build the website navigation system on the fly (you could probably even do it in CSS with :hover and display if you parsed the XML to HTML first) then you'd only be performing database queries on the nav system as and when it changes!

Even with the DOM manipulation, that's got to be more efficient, especially with large navigation systems, than nested SQL queries or recursive loops, surely.

---

***Note***

This is based on a blog entry a I wrote a couple of years ago and doesn't specifically match the question asked but this problem seems to crop up occasionally and this is the solution I came up with that *felt right* to me.

The principle is the same though - creating a nested navigation system whilst maintaining a good relational database structure.

I've made this a *community wiki* answer so more people can adapt it so that it better suits the specifics of the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

You tou have an category array with category_id and parent_id

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [parent] => 0
            [name] => Man
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [parent] => 0
        [name] => Woman
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [parent] => 1
        [name] => Tshirt
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [parent] => 1
        [name] => Jeans
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
        [parent] => 2
        [name] => woman jeans
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6
        [parent] => 2
        [name] => woman top
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [id] => 7
        [parent] => 3
        [name] => branded tshirt
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [id] => 8
        [parent] => 4
        [name] => branded jeans
    )
```

)

Answer (score 0):

```
function getCategory($category_array)
{   
foreach($category_array as $key => $category_data):
$cat_option_array;
if($category_data['parent']==0)
{
    $cat_option_array .= "<option value=".$category_data['id'].">".$category_data['name']."</option>";
    foreach($category_array as $subcategory_key => $subcategory_data):
    if($category_data['id']==$subcategory_data['parent'])
    {
        $cat_option_array .= "<option value=".$subcategory_data['id'].">--".$subcategory_data['name']."</option>";

        foreach($category_array as $level2categorykey => $level2category):

        if($level2category['parent']==$subcategory_data['id'])
        {
            $cat_option_array .= "<option value=".$level2category['id'].">----".$level2category['name']."</option>";
        }

        endforeach;
    }
    endforeach;
}
endforeach; 
echo $cat_option_array;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer for formatting, and merge your two answers into one.